# How to make total calculation sum vertically with DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following division calculation based on three measures in DAX:

Final Measure:= [Measure1]/([Measure2]/[Measure3])

which gives me the follwing result:

[image]

The current result generates the following total: 54/(65/45) = 37,8

How can you rewrite the "[Final Measure]" to make the total summarize the rows vertically rather than the measure dividing the total row columns.

Best regards,
Rubrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to use an iterator that sums up the row-by-row results in your total:

```
Total Measure :=
SUMX (
    'Table',
    [Measure1]/([Measure2]/[Measure3])
)
```

Comment: So this solution worked on the sample data but for some reason it didnt work with my real data (it just gave m 0) so I had to write it like this:
[Final Measure] = [Measure1]/([Measure2]/[Measure3])

[Final Measure Desired]=IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES('Test'[Country]))=1,[Final Measure] ,SUMX(VALUES('Test'[Country]),[Final Measure]))

Answer (score 1):

In PowerBi/Dax if you need to do this you have to use measures.
I juste created a dataset with your 3 columns as measures :

[image: Dataset]

Then you can use the aggregation with a CALCULATE function :

[image: Result]

As you can see with an aggregation function you'll find the expected result

Comment: Is it possible to solve it with a calculated measure rather than a calculated column ?

Comment: Best practice is to do exactly this - solve it using a measure instead. This is a more lightweight solution that is the way to go unless you plan to slice your data by the values generated in the calculated column, which in this case seems unlikely. See my answer for a measure solution using `SUMX`.